# React-Redux: rendering <Provider> inside function App()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have been trying to wrap my entire `App()` in `<Provider>` as instructed in Redux docs (to use my Redux store), like this:

```
import './App.css';
import MenuItems from './components/Navbar/MenuItems';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import {AddItemToCart, DeleteItemFromCart, Counter} from './cart.js';
import Header from './header';
import Footer from './footer.js';
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { useSelector, useStore } from 'react-redux';

let store = createStore(Counter);
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);

function App() {
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState()
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
  const [isLoaded, setStateToLoaded] = useState(false)
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [customerInfo, setCustomerInfo] = useState([]);
  const state = useSelector((state) => state);
  const cartContentsJSON = JSON.stringify(state);
```

This gives me the error:

```
Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>
```

This error crashes the app right after launching. The error disappears by deleting `useSelector()` on the last lines, but then the app won't work. I suspect it is because I'm using React DOM to render `<Provider>`, I probably shouldn't be using that since I'm using `function App()`? So I tried to add `<Provider>` inside `function App()` like this:

```
function App() {
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState()
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
  const [isLoaded, setStateToLoaded] = useState(false)
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [customerInfo, setCustomerInfo] = useState([]);
  const state = useSelector((state) => state);
  const cartContentsJSON = JSON.stringify(state);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="content">
      {!isLoaded && (
      <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
      </Provider>,
      rootElement
      )}
```

This however gives me another error message:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLDivElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

What is the most weird is that sometimes everything works after saving my edits, but stops to work if I refresh the page, this happens to me often with Redux. What I'm doing wrong? Any advise would be very highly appreciated

My `package.json`, is it possible that there is a compatibility issue?

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
```

Edit: The problem is solved. I tried to render  from `App.js` when I should have rendered from `index.js`.

Comment: Can you confirm that you do not have any other instance of the App running anywhere else

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri None that I'm aware of. I start debugging by running "npm start" in my project directory.

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a codesandbox with a reproducible error

Answer (score 0):

The obvious error here is a copy&paste one:

```js
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="content">
      {!isLoaded && (
      <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
      </Provider>,    // remove this comma
      rootElement     // remove this line
      )}
```

But that won't solve your problem itself. Rendering it just like you initally showed should be possible.

Your problem is most commonly caused by multiple versions of react, react-redux or react-dom being installed at the same time.

You can check that via `yarn why react` etc. Telling you how to fix it goes a bit beyond the scope of a stackOverflow question with a different question though - there are just too many options ;)

Comment: This seems to start recursion (page loads forever). I have added my package.json, is there a compatibility issue?

Comment: Well, your `App` components renders an `App` component. Yes, that's recursion ;)
That's what I meant by "your initial approach was right".

Your package.json is not necessarily all there is installed in your codebase. Package managers install all kind of stuff because it is dependency of a third package, so for all I know you could have 20 different react-dom versions there. You really have to use the tools provided by your package manager to search for that.

Comment: My package manager is npm. I created this project with create-react-app command. How would I check for multiple installed versions? My package.json and package-lock.json both contain only one.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I tried to render `<Provider>` from `App.js` when I should have rendered from `index.js`. Here is how my `index.js` looks like now:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { Counter } from './cart.js';

let store = createStore(Counter);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: you reallt should just have one of these two `ReactDOM.render` calls there though. Combine them into
```ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```